# Will this setup work?

Tags: mixer, zoom

[image: proposed setup]

I want to get sound from the laptop(music etc) and send it to the mixer (to play it to the speakers)

At the same time I want to get the sound from the mixer (the mic input, and the music that was sent by the laptop), to send it to obs => zoom.

Will this setup work?
The output and input from the mixer that I will be using is 2 track RCA.

Comment: You need an audio interface between the mixer and laptop

Comment: The computer already has a built in audio interface. the issue is how it is being used, and its capability.

Answer (score 2):

No. It won't. You are coming out of the mixer in stereo at line level, and at best, trying to get into the PC as mono at mic level. This isn't going to work.